# onClick vs onSubmit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple input in react that won't work with `onSubmit` but with `onClick`. Why is that? Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/8lqoryxj5j) to an example.

```js
const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const clicked = e => {
  alert("Hi")
}
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <input type='submit' value='click' onSubmit={clicked}/>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: please post the relevant code in the question

Comment: I have attached the link to a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onSubmit` is a prop for `<form>`, you should add the handler on to that element:

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <input ... />
</form>
```

Comment: Oh yah, yes, yes, you're right. But why would react allow me to use this handler without warning me or anything like that?

Comment: From MDN: The submit event fires when a <form> is submitted. Note that the submit event fires on the <form> element itself, and not on any <button> or <input type="submit"> inside it. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.).

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be in a `<form></form>` for submit to work

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thanks. Please read my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not submitting anything. onSubmit is for submitting forms...